# Difference in IL for ref paramters

Tags: c#, cil, ref

I am trying to understand the difference between the way parameters passed by reference and value are treated at IL level.

Here are the two methods in C#

```
    public static void TestRef(ref int x)
    {
        x++;
    }
    public static void Test(int x)
    {
        x++;
    }
```

The IL for pass by value is below, I understand that it loads the arg, then the int constant 1 and adds it and stuffs it back on the stack.

```
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0003:  add
  IL_0004:  starg.s    x
  IL_0006:  ret
```

The IL for the method which passes by reference:

```
IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  ldarg.0
  IL_0003:  ldind.i4
  IL_0004:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0005:  add
  IL_0006:  stind.i4
  IL_0007:  ret
```

I don't understand why the two `ldarg.0` statements are there. I assume the IL_0002/3 are just loading the argument address and then the argument value for that address.

But then what about IL_0001? Is it something to do with the left hand side of `x =x+1`?

Comment: The address loaded at `IL_0001:  ldarg.0` will be consumed by the storing operation at `IL_0006:  stind.i4`.

Comment: @thehennyy so for ref parameters the compiler allocates the additional address, since it knows that we are modifying the value? In case we do not modify the ref parameter then it does not need to load the address (IL_001)...at least looks like that in the example I tried. Can you update that in the ans, will mark it closed. Thanks

Comment: Yes the address is loaded a second time onto the stack and will be consumed later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address loaded at `IL_0001: ldarg.0` will be consumed by the storing operation at `IL_0006: stind.i4`.

The msdn tells us about the `stind.i4` opcode:

> The stack transitional behavior, in sequential order, is:
>
> 1. An address is pushed onto the stack.
> 2. A value is pushed onto the stack.
> 3. The value and the address are popped from the stack; the value is stored at the address.

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stind_i4?view=netframework-4.8